# Why do i get "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

I created search bar and when I press enter then send request to server.

HTML file:

```
<v-text-field
  outlined
  dense
  label="Search..."
  append-icon="mdi-magnify"
  @keydown.enter="searchEvent($event.target.value)"
></v-text-field>
```

TS file:

```
methods: {
        ...mapActions('event', ['searchEvent']),
        
        searchEvent(value: string){
            this.searchEvent(value)
}
```

VUEX file:

```
searchEvent({ commit}, value) {
        console.log(value)
        EventApi.search(value)
            .then( result => {
               commit('searchEvents', result.data)
            })
            .catch( error => {
            
                console.error("Error: ", {error:error});
                
            })
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
this.searchEvent(value)
```

Is calling itself, giving you an infinite recursive loop. Which eventually exceeds the stack size (limit). You should import `searchEvent` from Vuex such that the names don't clash. Maybe removing `this` could already be enough though.